# Running a list of steps in the spring batch by passing a start step name and end step name in the application arguments

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Is there a way in the spring batch if we can run a set of processing (multiple steps) by passing the name of the start step and end step in the application arguments. Our requirement is that we have a spring batch with 11 steps where each of the step has different reader, processor and writer. to pass step3 and step8 as arguments, so the batch processes each step between step3 and step8.

knowing that the steps are defined in the context xml file.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: This can only work if you can generate the bean names of each step in between. For `step3` to `step8` this can work, but if you have step bean names like `playerLoad`, `gameLoad` and `playerSummarization`, then it most certainly wont

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of specific requirements, you can use a [JobExecutionDecider](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/job/flow/JobExecutionDecider.html) and make it decide which step to execute or not based on application arguments.

You can find more details and a code example in the reference documentation here: [Programmatic Flow Decisions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#programmaticFlowDecisions).